# dll files compared to gzip files

Tags: dll, gzip, file-format

Okay, the title isn't very clear.

Given a byte array (read from a database blob) that represents EITHER the sequence of bytes contained in a .dll or the sequence of bytes representing the  gzip'd version of that dll, is there a (relatively) simple signature that I can look for to differentiate between the two?

I'm trying to puzzle this out on my own, but I've discovered I can save a lot of time by asking for help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it's first two bytes are the `gzip` magic number `0x1f8b` (see [RFC 1952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt)). Or just try to `gunzip` it, the operation will fail if the DLL is not `gzip`'d.

Answer (score 0):

A `gzip` file should be fairly straight forward to determine as it ought to consist of a header, footer and some other distinguishable elements in between.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip):

> "gzip" is often also used to refer to
>   the gzip file format, which is:
>
> - a 10-byte header, containing a magic
>     number, a version number and a time
>     stamp
> - optional extra headers, such as
>     the original file name
> - a body,
>     containing a DEFLATE-compressed
>     payload
> - an 8-byte footer, containing a
>     CRC-32 checksum and the length of the
>     original uncompressed data

You might also try determining if the `gzip` contains any records/entries as each will also have their own header.

You can find specific information on this file format (specifically the member header which is linked) [here](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer).